# Set a Data Frame Column as the Index of R data.frame object

Tags: r

Using R, how do I make a column of a dataframe the dataframe's index? Lets assume I read in my data from a .csv file. One of the columns is called 'Date' and I want to make that column the index of my dataframe.

For example in Python, NumPy, Pandas; I would do the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/mydata.csv')
d = df.set_index('Date')
```

Now how do I do that in R?

I tried in R:

```
df <- read.csv("/mydata.csv")
d <- data.frame(V1=df['Date'])
# or
d <- data.frame(Index=df['Date'])

# but these just make a new dataframe with one 'Date' column. 
#The Index is still 0,1,2,3... and not my Dates.
```

Comment: You probably want to use `data.table`? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html

Comment: the `index` you are saying is probably `row.names`, so, `row.names(d) <- df['Date']`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I assume that by "Index" you mean row names.  You can assign to the row names vector:

```
rownames(df) <- df$Date
```

Comment: But it keeps Date as a column of data frame ... How to remove it from columns ?

Comment: You can remove it by assigning `NULL` to the columns: `df$Date <- NULL`

Answer (score 24):

The index can be set while reading the data, in both pandas and R.

In pandas:

```python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/mydata.csv', index_col="Date")
```

In R:

```r
df <- read.csv("/mydata.csv", header=TRUE, row.names="Date")
```

Comment: For R, you can also give the column number for row.names. For instance if you want the first column to be the index, you can give row.names=1.

Answer (score 15):

The tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% column_to_rownames(., var = "Date")
```

Answer (score 0):

The function **match** is very helpful when you need the indices of a first vector in a second vector; example: after tabulating one vector, I have obtained a table with
2 columns, the first one with the items and the second one with the frequency; suppose that you need to add a 3rd column to the frequency table, with the description of the data in the first column, that belongs to another dataset that has a complete list of your data in column1 of the frequency table, and the related name in another column (like a "dictionary"). First you save the match between the items in the first column of the frequency table with the items name column of the "dictionary" dataset; then you can use the saved match to access the related names.

Answer (score -1):

while saving the dataframe use `row.names=F`
e.g. `write.csv(prediction.df, "my_file.csv", row.names=F)`

Comment: This answer is nothing to do with setting an index